# How to add java library to kotlin native

Tags: java, kotlin, kotlin-native

So I tried to create kotlin/native application using intellij (I selected template kotlin->kotlin/native in project creation). It created sample gradle hello world project. Which after downloading all dependencies compiles to exe file and runs normally. But now I need to include som libraries and I can't figure out how. For beginning I just want to include any jar library (for example jackson-core). This is how build.gradle file looks like:

```
plugins {
    id 'kotlin-multiplatform' version '1.3.0'
}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

kotlin {
    targets {
        // For ARM, preset should be changed to presets.iosArm32 or presets.iosArm64
        // For Linux, preset should be changed to e.g. presets.linuxX64
        // For MacOS, preset should be changed to e.g. presets.macosX64
        fromPreset(presets.mingwX64, 'mingw')

        configure([mingw]) {
            // Comment to generate Kotlin/Native library (KLIB) instead of executable file:
            compilations.main.outputKinds('EXECUTABLE')
            // Change to specify fully qualified name of your application's entry point:
            compilations.main.entryPoint = 'sample.main'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        // Note: To enable common source sets please comment out 'kotlin.import.noCommonSourceSets' property
        // in gradle.properties file and re-import your project in IDE.

        mingwMain {
        }
        mingwTest {
        }
    }
}


task runProgram {
    def buildType = 'release' // Change to 'debug' to run application with debug symbols.
    dependsOn "link${buildType.capitalize()}ExecutableMingw"
    doLast {
        def programFile = kotlin.targets.mingw.compilations.main.getBinary('EXECUTABLE', buildType)
        exec {
            executable programFile
            args ''
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

and

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

in every section and it doesn't help. I still can't import anything from jackson package and it doesn't show up in "external libraries" section of idea. I also tried specifying full name of lib and using something else instead of implementation or compile - still no result. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Kotlin/Native has no support for Java libraries. You need to use a multiplatform library ([kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)) or a native library such as [libjson](https://github.com/vincenthz/libjson).

Comment: What libraries are available by default? I just want to get the current time. There must be some default libraries.

Comment: There is now the kotlinx-datetime for getting the current time https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx-datetime